# Traefik with Service Fabric -- failed to connect to Service Fabric server

Tags: azure, cloud, reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric, traefik

I have deployed Traefik on my Azure Service Fabric cluster with the following configuration:

```
# Enable Service Fabric configuration backend
[servicefabric]

# Service Fabric Management Endpoint
clustermanagementurl = "https://localhost:19080"

# Service Fabric Management Endpoint API Version
apiversion = "3.0"

insecureSkipVerify = true
```

However, when opening the Traefik dashboard, I'm getting an empty screen, as it fails to map all my Fabric applications.

Looking at the Traefik logs on one of my VMs, I'm seeing this error repeatedly:

`level=error msg="failed to connect to Service Fabric server Get https://localhost:19080/Applications/?api-version=3.0: x509: certificate is valid for <hidden>.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com, not localhost on https://localhost:19080/Applications/?api-version=3.0"`

My Azure Service Fabric cluster has a SSL certificate signed by a trusted CA:
[image: Service Fabric management portal]

How can I solve this issue?

---

### Edit 1:

If it helps, this is the configuration Traefik loads (according to the logs):

```
{
    "LifeCycle": {
        "RequestAcceptGraceTimeout": 0,
        "GraceTimeOut": 0
    },
    "GraceTimeOut": 0,
    "Debug": true,
    "CheckNewVersion": true,
    "AccessLogsFile": "",
    "AccessLog": null,
    "TraefikLogsFile": "",
    "TraefikLog": null,
    "LogLevel": "DEBUG",
    "EntryPoints": {
        "http": {
            "Network": "",
            "Address": ":80",
            "TLS": null,
            "Redirect": null,
            "Auth": null,
            "WhitelistSourceRange": null,
            "Compress": false,
            "ProxyProtocol": null,
            "ForwardedHeaders": {
                "Insecure": true,
                "TrustedIPs": null
            }
        }
    },
    "Cluster": null,
    "Constraints": [],
    "ACME": null,
    "DefaultEntryPoints": [
        "http"
    ],
    "ProvidersThrottleDuration": 2000000000,
    "MaxIdleConnsPerHost": 200,
    "IdleTimeout": 0,
    "InsecureSkipVerify": true,
    "RootCAs": null,
    "Retry": null,
    "HealthCheck": {
        "Interval": 30000000000
    },
    "RespondingTimeouts": null,
    "ForwardingTimeouts": null,
    "Docker": null,
    "File": null,
    "Web": {
        "Address": ":9000",
        "CertFile": "",
        "KeyFile": "",
        "ReadOnly": false,
        "Statistics": null,
        "Metrics": null,
        "Path": "/",
        "Auth": null,
        "Debug": false,
        "CurrentConfigurations": null,
        "Stats": null,
        "StatsRecorder": null
    },
    "Marathon": null,
    "Consul": null,
    "ConsulCatalog": null,
    "Etcd": null,
    "Zookeeper": null,
    "Boltdb": null,
    "Kubernetes": null,
    "Mesos": null,
    "Eureka": null,
    "ECS": null,
    "Rancher": null,
    "DynamoDB": null,
    "ServiceFabric": {
        "Watch": false,
        "Filename": "",
        "Constraints": null,
        "Trace": false,
        "DebugLogGeneratedTemplate": false,
        "ClusterManagementURL": "https://localhost:19080",
        "APIVersion": "3.0",
        "UseCertificateAuth": false,
        "ClientCertFilePath": "",
        "ClientCertKeyFilePath": "",
        "InsecureSkipVerify": true
    }
}
```

---

### Edit 2:

One suggested to use the remote address of my cluster instead of `localhost`, doing so results in a different error:

`Provider connection error: failed to connect to Service Fabric server Get https://<hidden>.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Applications/?api-version=3.0: stream error: stream ID 1; HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED on https://<hidden>.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Applications/?api-version=3.0; retrying in 656.765021ms`

Comment: if your cluster is configured to connect using a certificate, you have to set `UseCertificateAuth: true` and specfy where the certificate is

Comment: What doc page specifies that?
What property should I use to specify the certificate?
Can I specify the cert inline? or it has to be a file path?

Comment: @johni How are you viewing the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Diego's comment (under my question) I succeeded solving this issue with the following additions.

## What was the problem?

1. My SF cluster is secured, requiring a client certificate to login -- **which was not specified in the Traefik TOML file**. (wish the error logged was more informative)
2. Looking at the Traefik logs, specifically on the SF part (look for the trace starting with `Starting provider *servicefabric.Provider` :

   ```
   "Watch": false,
   "Filename": "",
   "Constraints": null,
   "Trace": false,
   "DebugLogGeneratedTemplate": false,
   "ClusterManagementURL": "https://localhost:19080",
   "APIVersion": "3.0",
   "UseCertificateAuth": false,      <-------- Important
   "ClientCertFilePath": "",         <-------- Important
   "ClientCertKeyFilePath": "",      <-------- Important
   "InsecureSkipVerify": false
   ```

   - `UseCertificateAuth` -- indicates whether to use client certificate when Traefik queries the cluster's management endpoint.
   - `ClientCertFilePath` -- the path of the file containing the public key of the client certificate.
   - `ClientCertKeyFilePath` -- the path of the file containing the private key of the client certificate.

(both paths should be relative to the `traefik.exe`)

---

## InsecureSkipVerify

The Traefik's SF config (above) includes a setting called `InsecureSkipVerify`

- `InsecureSkipVerify` -- If set to `false`, then Traefik will reject the connection to the management endpoint unless the SSL certificate used is signed by a trusted CA.
- This could be an issue if the certificate is signed for the remote address, while Traefik uses `https://localhost` as the cluster's endpoint -- as then Traefik would print an error similar to this:

> failed to connect to Service Fabric server Get https://localhost:19080/Applications/?api-version=3.0: x509: certificate is valid for .eastus.cloudapp.azure.com, not localhost

To overcome this one, you can either

- Set `InsecureSkipVerify = true` and redeploy
- Set the management endpoint to the remote address:
  `clustermanagementurl = "https://<hidden>.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:19080"`

Thanks again Diego for giving me the hint that lead me to understand and share the above explanation.

Comment: johni - Are you able to clarify the settings that you are using to finally get this working? I'm unclear as to whether you are setting serviceFabric.tls settings (cert, key, insecureskipverify) as well as some other settings 'UseCertificateAuth', 'ClientCertFilePath', 'ClientCertKeyFilePath'. 

I have been wrestling with traefik for the longest and for the life of me I can not get mine to connect.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but we just ran into this exact situation and this is the ONLY place i've seen the client settings mentioned. This is the provider section that finally seems to have worked for us:

```
################################################################
# Service Fabric provider
################################################################

# Enable Service Fabric configuration backend
[servicefabric]

# Service Fabric Management Endpoint
clustermanagementurl = "https://localhost:19080"
# Note: use "https://localhost:19080" if you're using a secure cluster

# Service Fabric Management Endpoint API Version
apiversion = "3.0"

# Enable TLS connection.
#
# Optional
#
[serviceFabric.tls]
  cert               = "certs/servicefabric.crt"
  key                = "certs/servicefabric.key"
  insecureskipverify = true

UseCertificateAuth    =  true
ClientCertFilePath    = "certs/traefik.crt"
ClientCertKeyFilePath = "certs/traefik.key"
InsecureSkipVerify    =  true
```

Comment: `UseCertificateAuth = true` did the trick for me. But is there a reason why you have different crt and key files?

Comment: The servicefabric.crt is our Digicert/CA server cert and the traefik.crt is the client authentication cert. We're running gMSA security between nodes in the service fabric and client authentication for access security.

Comment: @ScottMcCollough just to confirm - is servicefabric.crt & key referencing the key in the ClusterConfig under `ServerCertificateCommonNames` and is traefik.crt & key referencing a key in the ClusterConfig under `ClientCertificateCommonNames` (with admin set to false?)

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate to ServiceFabric APIs, you have to use a certificate, in your configuration you miss this detail.

In the Traefik settings you should have something like this:

```
# [serviceFabric.tls]
cert = "certs/servicefabric.crt"
key = "certs/servicefabric.key"
insecureskipverify = true
```

The following post describe it step by step

https://blog.techfabric.io/using-traefik-reverse-proxy-for-securing-microservices-on-azure-service-fabric/

Comment: This doesn't work Diego (at least not on the latest Traefik version) due to: `failed to connect to Service Fabric server Get https://localhost:19080/Applications/?api-version=3.0: x509: certificate is valid for <hidden>.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com, not localhost`. However I managed to get it working thanks to your original comment, with the addition of setting `ClientCertKeyFilePath` and `ClientCertFilePath` settings.

Comment: As the error suggest, it is failing because of `ClusterManagementURL : https://localhost:19080` should be the url of your cluster, local cluster does not have security by default